# Could not find or load main class in Maven IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I can't run my project in intellij idea with maven.
This is my exceptions:
[image]
This is my project structure and my Run configurations
[image]

Maybe the problem in maven or other .iml files?
This is my tsp3.iml (you can see where it is in the photo above)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module version="4">
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="hibernate" name="Hibernate">
      <configuration>
        <datasource-map>
          <unit-entry name="hibernate.cfg.xml" value="128d993e-c8c2-47d8-a6c8-47085cb9ff4a" />
          <unit-entry name="res:hibernate.cfg.xml" value="128d993e-c8c2-47d8-a6c8-47085cb9ff4a" />
        </datasource-map>
        <naming-strategy-map />
        <deploymentDescriptor name="hibernate.cfg.xml" url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
      </configuration>
    </facet>
  </component>
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager">
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java/resources" type="java-resource" />
    </content>
  </component>
</module>
```

This is my .idea package:
[image]

My compiler.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
    <component name="CompilerConfiguration">
        <annotationProcessing>
            <profile name="Maven default annotation processors profile" enabled="true">
                <sourceOutputDir name="target/generated-sources/annotations" />
                <sourceTestOutputDir name="target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations" />
                <outputRelativeToContentRoot value="true" />
                <module name="tsp3" />
            </profile>
        </annotationProcessing>
    </component>
</project>
```

My modules.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="ProjectModuleManager">
    <modules>
      <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/tsp3.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/tsp3.iml" />
    </modules>
  </component>
</project>
```

I tried to add new application in Run-> Edit configuration and rebuild my project.

I tried to delete .idea and tsp3.iml. After restarting I had new package "target". Before and after deleting this package it didn't work. After that I deleted .idea and tsp3.iml again and there wasn't "target" in my project but it still doesn't work. I think the problem can be in compiler.xml in .idea because there are two folder paths with "target" in it. But I don't know what I should write there.

This is my compiler.xml now:
[image]

I will be grateful for your help!

Comment: Was project built? There is no out/target folder in the project tree.

Comment: Try to remove the out/target folder and rebuild the project from scratch via Build | Build Project action

Answer (score 1):

Close your IDE and delete the `.idea` folder and `tsp3.iml` file from the root of the project and reload the project.

Most issues for intellij are solved by removing the `.idea` folder.

```
rm -rf .idea *.iml
```

Comment: It does not work for me. After I connected to my DB I had exception because of my hibernate.cnfg.xml. When I fixed that I had the same exception:Error: Could not find or load main class org.example.App
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.example.App

Comment: Plus I have package "target" with hibernate.cnfg.xml, that I did not create before. After deleting it still doesn't work

Comment: @doradura Is it a spring boot application ?

Comment: No,it's maven without spring boot i think